# Not able to get the Latitude and Longitude while using 'GeoLocator' package

Tags: flutter, dart

1. I am trying to use 'GeoLocator' to retrieve Latitude & Longitude. However, not able to get any output?
2. Also will be helpful if someone can help me organize the 'geoLocator' package as a service in a separate dart file.
3. As suggested I tried changing the code, but still not able to get the geolocation. Also when I call the '_determinePosition()' getting "Instance of 'Future'
   ".

> ```
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
>
> class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
>   @override
>   _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
> }
>
> class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
>   //
>
>   Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
>     bool serviceEnabled;
>     LocationPermission permission;
>
>     // Test if location services are enabled.
>     serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
>     if (!serviceEnabled) {
>       return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
>     }
>
>     permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
>     if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
>       permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
>       if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
>         // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
>         return Future.error(
>             'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
>       }
>
>       if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
>         return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
>       }
>     }
>
>     return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
>   }
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     // TESTIST IF PRINT CAN WORK HERE
>     print(_determinePosition());
>     return Scaffold(
>       appBar: AppBar(
>         title: Text("Location"),
>       ),
>       body: Center(
>         child: Column(
>           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
>           children: <Widget>[
>             TextButton(
>               child: Text("Get location"),
>               onPressed: () {
>                 // PRINTING IN THE CONSOLE
>                 _determinePosition();
>               },
>             ),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: did you add relevant permissions for both android and ios as specified in the doc ?

Comment: Yes in the AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add the Internet permission in addition to the location permissions per the documentation (https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Regarding getting "intsantce of a Future" instead of the result you need to await the call to _determinePosition() just like this:

```
onPressed: () async{
            // PRINTING IN THE CONSOLE
           await _determinePosition();
          },
```

For using Geolocator as a service I recommend to use a dependency injection solution like Provider(https://pub.dev/packages/provider) or GetIt(https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

Answer (score 1):

Use below function which checks the permission and returns current position, so before getting location it's important to check whether we had required permission or not.

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

/// Determine the current position of the device.
///
/// When the location services are not enabled or permissions
/// are denied the `Future` will return an error.
Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  // Test if location services are enabled.
  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    // Location services are not enabled don't continue
    // accessing the position and request users of the 
    // App to enable the location services.
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately. 
      return Future.error(
        'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    } 

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      // Permissions are denied, next time you could try
      // requesting permissions again (this is also where
      // Android's shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale 
      // returned true. According to Android guidelines
      // your App should show an explanatory UI now.
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }

  // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
  // continue accessing the position of the device.
  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jitesh, tried changing the code as you suggested, but still, no location in the console could be retrieved!!!

Comment: so after adding location permission its running?